# Multiple custom Streetview generation

Tags: google-maps-api-3, panoramas, google-street-view

I want to show another streetview pane on the screen.
I bound the "redraw()" function to the button onclick event.
The calling of redraw() function from the onclick event failed to draw another streetview.

When redraw() function is called in the initialize() function it works well.

Q1. Why does this redraw() fucnction behaves differently ? 
Q2. How can I make it work as I wanted ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Simple Custom StreetView</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
  var tileSize, worldSize;
  var panorama = null;
  var panorama1 = null;
  var panoOptions = null;
  var panoOptions1 = null;

  function initialize() {
    // Set up Street View and initially set it visible. Register the
    // custom panorama provider function. Set the StreetView to display
    // the custom panorama 'reception' which we check for below.
    panoOptions = {
      pano: 'reception',
      visible: true,
      panoProvider: getCustomPanorama
    }; 
    tileSize = 1024;
    worldSize = 1024;
    panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('pano_canvas'), panoOptions);
   //redraw();

  }

  function redraw() {
    // Set up Street View and initially set it visible. Register the
    // custom panorama provider function. Set the StreetView to display
    // the custom panorama 'reception' which we check for below.

    tileSize = 1024;
    worldSize = 1024;

    panoOptions1 = {
      pano: 'reception1',
      visible: true,
      panoProvider: getCustomPanorama1
    };

    panorama1 = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('pano_canvas1'), panoOptions1);
  }

  // Return a pano image given the panoID.
  function getCustomPanoramaTileUrl(pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
    // Note: robust custom panorama methods would require tiled pano data.
    // Here we're just using a single tile, set to the tile size and equal
    // to the pano "world" size.
    return 'panoReception1024-0.jpg';
  }


  // Return a pano image given the panoID.
  function getCustomPanoramaTileUrl1(pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
    // Note: robust custom panorama methods would require tiled pano data.
    // Here we're just using a single tile, set to the tile size and equal
    // to the pano "world" size.
    return 'panoReception1024-0.jpg';
  }

  // Construct the appropriate StreetViewPanoramaData given
  // the passed pano IDs.
  function getCustomPanorama(pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
    if (pano == 'reception') {
      return {
        location: {
          pano: 'reception',
          description: 'Google Sydney - Reception'
        },
        links: [],
        // The text for the copyright control.
        copyright: 'Imagery (c) 2010 Google',
        visible: true,
        // The definition of the tiles for this panorama.
        tiles: {
          tileSize: new google.maps.Size(tileSize, 512),
          worldSize: new google.maps.Size(worldSize, 512),
          // The heading in degrees at the origin of the panorama
          // tile set.
          centerHeading: 105,
          getTileUrl: getCustomPanoramaTileUrl
        }
      };
    }
  }


  // Construct the appropriate StreetViewPanoramaData given
  // the passed pano IDs.
  function getCustomPanorama1(pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
    if (pano == 'reception1') {
      return {
        location: {
          pano: 'reception1',
          description: 'Google Sydney - Reception'
        },
        links: [],
        visible: true,
        // The text for the copyright control.
        copyright: 'Imagery (c) 2010 Google',
        // The definition of the tiles for this panorama.
        tiles: {
          tileSize: new google.maps.Size(tileSize, 512),
          worldSize: new google.maps.Size(worldSize, 512),
          // The heading in degrees at the origin of the panorama
          // tile set.
          centerHeading: 105,
          getTileUrl: getCustomPanoramaTileUrl1
        }
      };
    }
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>
 <b>Tile Size: </b>
 <select id="tileSize" >
  <option value="256">256</option>
  <option value="512">512</option>
  <option value="768">768</option>
  <option value="1024" selected>1024</option>
  <option value="2048">2048</option>
  </select>
  <b>World Size: </b>
  <select id="worldSize" >
  <option value="256">256</option>
  <option value="512">512</option>
  <option value="768">768</option>
  <option value="1024" selected>1024</option>
  <option value="2048">2048</option>
  </select>
<input type="button" value="Redraw" id="redraw" onclick="redraw()" />
  </div>
  <div id="pano_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 380px"></div>
  <div id="pano_canvas1" style="width: 500px; height: 380px"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found how to make it work but still am not sure why.
In the redraw() function, I added setPano() as below.

```
panorama1 = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano_canvas1'), panoOptions1);
panorama1.setPano('reception1');
```

Then the redraw() function worked as expected.
Without that, the custom panoProvider function was not called.
I suppose setPano calls the custom panoProvider function internally.